# htaccess rewrite characters in link and to a different directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am moving a large site with over 20 thousand pages and misc documents out of an old dream press site into a wordpress site. The structure of the old website is a mess. There are misc documents of many different types scattered into hundreds of different folders at different levels. If possible I would like to not break all of the old links and yet go to a more logical structure.

With that in mind I am starting with the pdf documents. An old link would look like

```
http://www.example.org/agriculture/gaoag/092505.pdf
```

To simplify it I am wanting to put all of the pdf files in a single folder. To make sure I do not have naming problems and to be able to redirect old links to now ones I replaced the '/' with '_' Doing that a new link would look like.

```
http://www.example.org/pdf/agriculture_gaoag_092505.pdf
```

I can automate that part, where I am having problems is redirecting the old links to new ones. I would think with .htaccess it should be possible to replace the '/' with underscore and go to a new directory all at once.

With the code below I can redirect to the correct folder. How do I also get it to change the / to _ ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.pdf$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pdf
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pdf/$1 [R,L]
```

Edit: Adding another example

```
http://www.example.org/BOR/2011/2011/OPS/PLAN/040611.pdf
```

Hoping to get

```
http://www.example.org/pdf/BOR_2011_2011_OPS_PLAN_040611.pdf
```

Note: I am using a .htaccess file in the root level. If needed I am willing to make them other places as well.

Note 2: there can be anywhere from no / to 7 deep that need to get changed.

Note 3: Once I get this working I will be making variations for other file types.

Comment: _“I would think with .htaccess it should be possible to replace the '/' with underscore”_ - well if you already _think_ that, then you might as well make an effort to actually _research_ it, too ... https://www.google.com/search?q=mod_rewrite+replace+character+in+url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pdf
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/(.+)/([0-9]+)\.pdf$
RewriteRule ^   /pdf/%1_%2_%3.pdf [R=301,L]
```

But if you want to follow the same criteria for other files you could gather them like this, for example :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(pdf|js|css|html)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^    /%4/%1_%2_%3.%4 [R=301,L]
```

As per your comment and that you have different levels , try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(pdf|js|css|html)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$   /$1_$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(pdf|js|css|html)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  \.(pdf|js|css|html)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$   /%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache the test.

Comment: That is getting close! That redirects to the folder and will fix 2 of the / There are some files that have as many as 7 / Also what you posted refuses to remove the first / even if there is just one.

Comment: @Brandan what you mentioned in you question is what i relied on in answer , so the rules is working only with example you gave

Comment: Mentioned in notes, added another example.

Comment: Not sure I understand why that works, but it does! I ended up adding RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d Aside from that perfection!

Comment: @Brandan thanks for your comment , i I will explain to you how does it works , the first rule will capture any uri like for example /1/2/3/4.whatever then change it to /1_2/3/4.whatever then to /1_2_3/4.whatever then /1_2_3_4.whatever so the first rule will work until there is no / in URI , in the second rule i capture that /output.whatever ,/1_2_3_4.whatever and redirect it to /whatever/1_2_3_4.whatever , you got it?